# What are typical work-out weight ratios for some compound and isolation exercises (bench-press weight vs. triceps push-down weight for example)?

Tags: weightlifting

I am not sure if my arms are weak, so that they hinder my progress in compound exercises like bench-press or pull-down. I know that, for beginners it is generally advised to focus on compound exercises, as they will also help arm development. But I think it is also possible that, due to weaker arms, chest and back can not get enough tension. If this is the case, then concentrating on biceps/triceps first may be more beneficial. So, do you have any suggestions to figure out if biceps/triceps is the limiting factor?

Comment: There may be a conversion rate for free weights, but if you are referring to machines, then there is no conversion rate as every machine is different. See http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/31784/18977 for more details on the weights listed on machines.